# How to set conditions for HABTM relation

Tags: php, cakephp

In kid model i have defined this below HABTM relation.

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array( 
    'Pics' => array(
        'className' => 'Pic',
        'joinTable' => 'pics_kids',
        'foreignKey' => 'kid_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'pic_id'
    )
);
```

Pics table store details of pics like comment, pic_url and date and pics_kids table have pic_id and kid_id id's that relate pic and kids . If i have to retrieve record based on kid_id and date(date of pic in pics table) how to retrieve it?

```
$kid_pics=$this->kid->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'kid.id' => 1,
        'Pic.date' => '26/07/2014'
    )
));
```

if i use above query i get error that no column Pic.date in where claue.

Comment: have u tried `$this->Kid->Pic->find` ?

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition to your HATBM relationship dynamically:

```
$this->Kid->hasAndBelongsToMany['Pic']['conditions'] = array(
    'Pic.date' => '26/07/2014'
) ;
$kid_pics = $this->Kid->real(null, 1) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in Containable Behavior

```
$this->Kid->Behaviors->load('Containable');

$kid_pics = $this->Kid->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Kid.id' => 1
    ),
    'contain' => array(
        'Pic' => array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Pic.date' => '26/07/2014'
            )
        )
    )
));
```